# Blender Hair System uses different seed on different computers

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hair, network

I am trying to render a pretty complex hair setup on our local network of workstations with cycles X. I use 3.0.0. The machines all render to our production server with placeholders. Works fine normally.

The problem is that, apparently, the hair systems use a seed specific to each machine. That's a problem, since they are jittering and jumping around, when seen in sequence.

The hair systems are simple, non-dynamic setups. So i can't bake a Cache. Converting is also not an option, since it's millions of hairs.

Is there any way to fix this? I saw a few threads about this from 2017, but I recon stuff has changed since then.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi :). Which threads have you read/tried? The particle system hasn't changed in a looong time, so older solutions could still work ;)